# How to use use as in linux with assembly language

Tags: linux, assembly, kernel

I am studying Linux kernel, so I have to read some assembly code. Here is a sample code

---

```
SYSWRITE=4
.globl mywrite,myadd
.text
mywrite:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    pushl %ebx
    movl 8(%ebp),%ebx
    movl 12(%ebp),%ecx
    movl 16(%ebp),%edx
    movl $SYSWRITE,%eax
    int $0x80
    popl %ebx
    movl %ebp,%esp
    popl %ebp
    ret

myadd:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    movl 8(%ebp),%eax
    movl 12(%ebp),%edx
    xorl %ecx,%ecx
    addl %eax,%edx
    jo 1f
    movl 16(%ebp),%eax
    movl %edx,(%eax)
    incl %ecx
1:  
    movl %ecx,%eax
    movl %ebp,%esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

I  use the as in this way 

**"as -o callee.o callee.s"** 

to compile it,but it fails with a message saying something like this 

**"callee.s|5| Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'"**

Comment: Near duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain, which talks about `gcc` and `ld`, but not `as`.  (You can use `gcc -m32 foo.S` to assemble and link.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably on a 64-bit machine, so your `as` defaults to 64-bit.  Since you have 32-bit code, you want to use:

```
as -32 -o callee.o callee.s
```